# changing TrustManager's accepted issuers during TLS renegotiation

Tags: java, netty, ssl

In my current netty (3.5.2) based server [I am able to ask the client for a certificate using TLS renegotiation](https://github.com/bblfish/Play20/blob/TLS/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/server/netty/PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala#L82). Depending on the type of resource, I would like to ask the client for a different set of certificates. This can be done by the server sending the TLS  [CertificateRequest signal with the `certificate_authorities` field](http://www.w3.org/2005/Incubator/webid/spec/#requesting-the-client-certificate) set correctly. The two sets of resources I would like to distinguish on my server are:

1. default: resources that ask certificates of the client that have been signed by CAs known to the `X509TrustManager`
2. resources that would like to see ANY certificate of the user - this is useful for services designed to help debug client certificates ( send me any certificate you have, I'll tell you if it conforms to all the standards we know on the subject )

In Java the list of trusted CAs is set by the [X509TrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html) method. But once the SSLContext set there does not seem to be a way to alter this. I expected some option to be available from the [SSLParameters class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLParameters.html) but there is no method that would allow one to at least set the null `certificate_authorities` list.

One unsatisfactory way to allow this would be to open a new port for null requested certificate authorities, and so distinguish the resources by separating them into these different ports. Is there perhaps a hack anyone knows of to avoid opening a new port?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install your own TrustManager. See the JSSE Reference Guide for details.

Comment: yes, I can set my TrustManager on the command line as [I explain on the RWWPlay wiki page](https://github.com/read-write-web/rww-play#getting-going) ( see implementation in [NettyServer](https://github.com/bblfish/Play20/blob/44d532cadb9fbdcb4c42e20e71de45f1d668fab5/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/server/NettyServer.scala#L43) class). That is not the problem. The problem is that this does not allow the `Servlet`(`Action` in Play) to select the TrustManager. I cannot have two different resources on the same TLS port 1 asking for null cert_auth list and the other for default.